# How do I run a video in a PyQt container?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, pyqt5

In the QVideoWidget container on PyQt, you need to start a video from the computer, on which objects are to be searched through TensorFlow (openCV, cv2). The problem is that when the button is pressed, the video only shows one frame and nothing else. What could be the problem? Made in PyCharm, Python 3.7.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uiс
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap

class ThreadOpenCV(QThread):
    changePixmap = pyqtSignal(QImage)

    def __init__(self, source):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):

        # MODEL_NAME = 'inference_graph'
        VIDEO_NAME = '20201024161726.mp4'
        #
        # # Grab path to current working directory
        CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()
        PATH_TO_VIDEO = os.path.join(CWD_PATH, VIDEO_NAME)
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(PATH_TO_VIDEO)
        while True:
            ret, frame = cap.read()

            if ret:
                frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                frame_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame_rgb, axis=0)
                rgbImage = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                h, w, ch = rgbImage.shape
                bytesPerLine = ch * w
                convertToQtFormat = QImage(rgbImage.data, w, h, bytesPerLine, QImage.Format_RGB888)
                p = convertToQtFormat.scaled(640, 480, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

                self.changePixmap.emit(p)

                if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                    break
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()


class Widget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        uic.loadUi('fire_detection.ui', self)
        self.show()

        self.label_video = QLabel()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label_video)

        self.widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.thread = ThreadOpenCV('20201024161726.mp4')
        self.thread.changePixmap.connect(self.setImage)

        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.playVideo)

    def playVideo(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def setImage(self, image):
        self.label_video.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mw = Widget()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `waitKey` is useless if you don't display cv2 window. You should rathern use `while running:` and set `running =False` when you want to exit loop.

Comment: you may have problem because you have wrong indentations and you run `cap.release()` inside `while True` - so it release it after first frame.

Comment: if you don't create window with `cv2.imshow` (or similar) then you don't need `cv2.destroyAllWindows()`

Comment: thanks for answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All problem is because you have wrong indentations - and you run `cap.release()` inside `while`-loop so it releases stream after the first frame.

```
   while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if ret:
            frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            frame_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame_rgb, axis=0)

            rgbImage = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            h, w, ch = rgbImage.shape
            bytesPerLine = ch * w
            convertToQtFormat = QImage(rgbImage.data, w, h, bytesPerLine, QImage.Format_RGB888)
            p = convertToQtFormat.scaled(640, 480, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

            self.changePixmap.emit(p)

   # --- after `while` ---

   cap.release()
```

---

You don't create window in `cv2` so you don't `cv2.destroyAllWindows()`.
And `cv2.waitKey(1)` will be also useless because the system sends key/mouse events to `cv2` only when it displays the window and this window is active (focused).

---

**EDIT:**

Full working code. It uses a webcam.

It doesn't need a `UI` file.

It has buttons to start and stop streaming,

It has also buttons to switch: RGB <-> GRAYSCALE, NORMAL <-> BLURED.

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import cv2

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap

class ThreadOpenCV(QThread):
    
    changePixmap = pyqtSignal(QImage)

    def __init__(self, source):
        super().__init__()

        self.source = source

        self.running = True
        self.grayscale = False
        self.blur = False
        
    def run(self):
        print('start')

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.source)

        self.running = True
        
        while self.running:
            ret, frame = cap.read()

            if ret:
                if self.grayscale:
                    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
                else:
                    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                    
                if self.blur:
                    frame = cv2.blur(frame, (15, 15))

                h, w, ch = frame.shape
                bytes_per_line = ch * w   # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables
                
                image = QImage(frame.data, w, h, bytes_per_line, QImage.Format_RGB888)
                image = image.scaled(640, 480, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

                self.changePixmap.emit(image)
            
        cap.release()
        print('stop')
        
    def stop(self):
        self.running = False


class Widget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # MODEL_NAME = 'inference_graph'
        VIDEO_NAME = '20201024161726.mp4'
        CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()
        PATH_TO_VIDEO = os.path.join(CWD_PATH, VIDEO_NAME)
       
        # webcam
        PATH_TO_VIDEO = 0

        self.thread = ThreadOpenCV(PATH_TO_VIDEO)
        self.thread.changePixmap.connect(self.setImage)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.label_video = QLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.label_video)

        self.btn1 = QPushButton("PLAY")
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.playVideo)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn1)

        self.btn_stop = QPushButton("STOP")
        self.btn_stop.clicked.connect(self.stopVideo)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn_stop)
        
        self.btn_gray = QPushButton("RGB <-> GRAYSCALE")
        self.btn_gray.clicked.connect(self.grayVideo)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn_gray)

        self.btn_blur = QPushButton("NORMAL <-> BLURED")
        self.btn_blur.clicked.connect(self.blurVideo)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn_blur)

        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        
    def playVideo(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def stopVideo(self):
        self.thread.running = False

    def grayVideo(self):
        self.thread.grayscale = not self.thread.grayscale

    def blurVideo(self):
        self.thread.blur = not self.thread.blur

    def setImage(self, image):
        self.label_video.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    mw = Widget()
    mw.show()
    
    app.exec()
```

RGB, NORMAL:

[image]

GRAYSCALE, BLURED:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped)