# Python - Set timestamp in video on keypress

Tags: python, opencv, video, event-handling, video-processing

I cannot find any solution online, so I resort to Stackoverflow to pose my question.

For a Python video-player implementation, I want to add an on key-press event. With this event, a timestamp will be written to a json file. This timestamp should be the exact time at which the key was pressed while watching the video (e.g. 05m22s).

I am wondering whether anybody knows how to do this with opencv, ffprobe/ffmpeg, moviepy, pyAV, or literally any other library that allows video processing? I am stuck on linking the "key pressed" action with the actual time that the video is playing at. All the rest I can handle.

Comment: What GUI library are you using? That will be responsible for connecting your keypress callback to the function that will do printout.

Comment: Currently I'm using PyQt5, but if something like Pygame is easier, I could also switch to that.

Answer (score 2):

I am not too familiar with pyqt5; I am using pygtk4 because I'm developing for linux and gnome, but that doesn't change the steps you need to take:

- build your user interface and designate a container for your video. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67488022/how-do-i-run-a-video-in-a-pyqt-container) is an example for using pyqt; other libraries have analogous containers;
- add a keypress [signal handler](https://learndataanalysis.org/example-of-how-to-use-the-qwidget-keypress-event-pyqt5-tutorial/) to the container;
- write a callback function when you click on the play button for your video that stores the current timestamp (for example, `ts = time.time()`);
- write a callback function to do whatever you want to happen when you press a key, i.e. compute the time difference between then and when you pressed play (for example, `diff = time.time() - ts`).

Comment: Sounds like a good plan! Thanks a lot for your input!